# c# blazor avoid using 'async' lambda when delegate type returns 'void'

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, delegates, blazor

I get the following warning in JetBrains Rider and I can't find a way to workaround it.
It's a blazor WASM project with .net 6.

> Avoid using 'async' lambda when delegate type returns 'void'

Sample code Razor:

```
<Validation Validator="async e => await ValidateFieldAsync(e)">
```

Sample code c#:

```
protected async Task ValidateFieldAsync(ValidatorEventArgs args)
{
    // Some code with awaits etc.
}
```

Jetbrains describes this warning here:

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AsyncVoidLambda.html

But what is the best practice here to fix this?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Resharper lost track here. The warning is incorrect.

But you can improve this anyway,

```
<Validation Validator="e => ValidateFieldAsync(e)">
```

As long as ValidateFieldAsync() still returns `async Task`
this is still async and awaitable, just with a little less overhead. The `aync` and `await` in the lambda were adding an extra layer that isn't needed.
And it might just stop that false warning, I can't check now.

When you don't need any argument or when Blazor can auto add it then you can follow @MisterMagoo's answer.

Comment: "When you don't need an e you can follow @MisterMagoo's answer." This statement implies that when you need the `ValidatorEventArgs`, you should not follow @MisterMagoo's answer, right ? No, you're wrong. The `ValidatorEventArgs` is automatically passed to the event handler by the framework, which is exactly why `Mister Magoo` uses Validator="ValidateFieldAsync" for the method signature `protected async Task ValidateFieldAsync(ValidatorEventArgs args)`

Comment: The question is about Resharper, not all arguments can be auto-filled.

Comment: If that is the case, @Mister Magoo's answer is wrong, and I shouldn't have upvoted his answer. I guess not...

Comment: I tested it the way stated, this only gives a new warning:  

"Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

I'll open a bug report on the jetbrains tracker to get rid of the original warning which seems displayed by error.

Comment: Yes, this is for Resharper. Apparently it can't 'predict' the code generated by Razor. I would still always use the short form though.

Comment: `ValidateFieldAsync` as written in the question does not "return an async Task" as stated in the answer. It returns void, and should be awaited which is why you get the new warning using this syntax. Remove the async modifier from the Method signature and return a Task from the method body and then it would remove the warning, but you are still using a lambda unnecessarily while you only have one argument to provide to the ValidateFieldAsync method.

Comment: @MisterMagoo - unclear what you mean here. The lambda will return a Task and will be awaited. The situation of 1 parameter (that can be eliminated) already was "a bad sample with only one parameter".

Comment: No, the Razor engine is smart enough to detect that the lambda returns a Task. Resharper is wrong, the question is fine (the sample a little weak maybe).

Comment: In the code I posted here the `<Validation />` control can await its Validator callback, the await chain is unbroken.

Comment: I've decided I'm unclear what I mean, so I have deleted my comments and will leave you  to it

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a lambda here at all.

```html
<Validation Validator="ValidateFieldAsync" >
```

or

```html
<Validation Validator=@ValidateFieldAsync >
```

or

```html
<Validation Validator=ValidateFieldAsync >
```

Should all work - it is just a matter of your preference for style.

You are correct to return a Task from this method.

Comment: I used a bad sample with only one parameter, with multiple parameter this can not be done that way. But in context of the sample this would be right.

Comment: That is true. If your method define multiple parameters, you should use lambada expression, passing those parameters to the method, and don't use the keyword `async` before the parameter list Do something like this:  `Validator="@( (e) => await ValidateFieldAsync(e, index))"`, the variable `index`, being something you define in your code...

Comment: It really is best to ask the question you want answered.

Answer (score -1):

When calling functions from razor don't call `Task` functions. Call `void` functions because that is what is expected.

```
<Validation Validator="e => ValidateFieldAsync(e)">
```

Then the actual code:

```
protected async void ValidateFieldAsync(ValidatorEventArgs args)
{
    // Some code with awaits etc.
}
```

It will still run async so don't worry about having `async` in the razor calling code.

Comment: This is bad advice - you should only use async void for an EventHandler - all Blazor EventCallbacks should return a Task when they are asynchronous.